# Electron App webview.printToPDF() "Save As..." Dialog

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I am creating an Electron App that uses is a wrapper for a Web App by using a `<webview>` element.

I am wanting to allow the users to create a PDF of any page by simply clicking a Button and selecting where to save the PDF.

The code in the Electron examples allows for saving in a hardcoded location every time.

```
document.querySelector("#pdf").onclick = function () {
    webview.printToPDF({}, (error, data) => {
        if (error) throw error
            fs.writeFile('/tmp/print.pdf', data, (error) => {
        if (error) throw error
            console.log('Write PDF successfully.')
        })
    });
};
```

This works fine but will save in the same location every time and does not allow the user to select a location or name.

Is there an option to show a "Save As..." dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do the save process server-side (send an IPC command and execute the save from the main.js file of electron).

Anyway, to address your issue, I don't know whether there is an official "Save As" button, but you may implement something pretty similar to it:

## Solution 1 -- Using the Web API:

There is a sort of "save as" (well, technically it just asks you for a directory, but you can really edit the button values.. so the only thing you will miss is the filename here) built-in with webkit, you can basically do something like this:

```
<input id="savePath" type="file" webkitdirectory />
```

Next, add an event listener to the button:

```
let fpHandler = document.getElementByID("savePath");
fpHandler.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
   const path = event.target.files[0].path;
   // save file happens here.
});
```

where path contains the selected path without any slash or backslash at the end of the string (so you will need to add that manually, like: `const filepath = path + "\\" + filename_and_format;`

## Solution 2 -- Using the electron API.

I didn't try this one, but I'm sure it works.

Basically, the trick is using **electron remote**: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/ which can be used in the renderer process.

the **remote** module exposes the **dialog** gui related module: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/

So you can really do this by using the showSaveDialog: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options-callback

```
const { remote } = require("electron");
remote.dialog.showSaveDialog(remote.getCurrentWindow(), (filename) => {
   console.log("filename is: " + filename);
   // here the save should happen.
});
```

Comment: I used an implementation of Solution 2 to solve my issue.

Comment: @MichaelSmith: Yep it's likely the "proper" way to do it if you don't like the wekbit way. The callbacks available however are pretty great ;) I'm glad it helped